# How do I put a param using number into facebook graph api function in facebook plugin framework.

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, frameworks, cocos2d-x

I use SDKBox to use facebook framework. And I want to set a user score.

So I used the api function as same as the sample code.

but api function has support only string value. not a integer or boolean else.

how can I use it by param as number.

I tried to put a json string to parameter. like {"score":10000} ( It was returned succeess. but there was nothing to changed. )

I tried to put a string value like "10000" (It retured failed. The message was "(#100) Param score must be a number" )

Is there any difference way to set a score? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Self answer :

I was bad.

It worked well. I thought I tried the second way on the text.

but actually I tried just like wrong way like below.

params["score"] = 100;

right way is

params["score"] = "100";

It worked well.

I will not delete the question for the anyone who makes mistakes like me.